# Kierkegaard and Natural Sciences

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kierkegaard

Is there any overlap in Kierkegaard's work and Philosophy of Science? If my memory is not misleading, Søren's journals had plenty of mathematical and scientific examples, but used for the most part to clarify an unrelated statement. Did he ever write about natural sciences, or something we would call nowadays (even if wrongly) philosophy of science?